# Print out specific variables based on time index in xarray.Dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, dataset, netcdf, python-xarray

I've accessed a netCDF file using `nc = xarray.open_dataset(...)`. The Dataset contains the following:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 121, longitude: 261, time: 8760)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 -20.0 -19.75 -19.5 -19.25 ... 44.5 44.75 45.0
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 55.0 54.75 54.5 54.25 ... 25.5 25.25 25.0
  * time       (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 ... 1979-12-31T23:00:00
Data variables:
    u10        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    v10        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
    msl        (time, latitude, longitude) float32 ...
Attributes:
    Conventions:  CF-1.6
    history:      2020-11-24 08:15:21 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.16.0: /opt/ecmw...
```

Using `nc.to_dataframe()`, I was able to print out a "better looking" format of the data like this:

[image]

From here, I want to print out the `u10` (and later `v10`) values just for September, meaning from `1979-01-01 00:00:00` to `1979-10-01 00:00:00`. The index of `nc` is a

`MultiIndex([(55.0, -20.0, '1979-01-01 00:00:00'), ... names=['latitude', 'longitude', 'time'], length=276649560)`

I'm not sure if the MultiIndex part helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest learning the basics of `xarray` first. They have some well-written [examples](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples.html) on how to get started. For your case, check these examples on [how to select data.](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html)

In your case

```
t1 = '1979-01-01 00:00:00'
t2 = '1979-10-01 00:00:00'
## select data from t1 till t2
a = nc.u10.sel(time=slice(t1, t2))
print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a step forward in data selection, but I still have to use it in combination with `nc.to_dataframe()` to print it out in a column instead of a  `121 x 261` dimensional grid. Any tips on how to achieve that without using  `dataframe` and saving it with `.to_csv`?

Comment: You can just do `nc.sel(time=slice(t1, t2)).to_dataframe()` and you gonna have the dataframe for the selected time range only. Does it helps?

Comment: @aLjeonjko Do you want to save values for just one grid-point, eg; 55.0, -20.0 in a CSV?